# Angular2 ng-bootstrap carousel multiple frames

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Is it possible to configure ng-bootstrap carousel directive `NgbCarousel` to show multiple frames at once?
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Did you figure it out by any chance?

Comment: I'm also wanting to do this now.